# Use PHP in dropboxlist and it doesnt work well

Tags: javascript, php, dropbox

I want to see data with dropboxlist . But it dosen't work well

on my dropbox, just could see "-- CHOOSE --" and "firstdata of DB"

like

(-- CHOOSE --  <- dropbox

DBlist1 )               <- dropbox

DBlist2        <-- not dropbox. just text

DBlist3 <-- not dropbox. just text

DBlist4 <-- not dropbox. just text

```
<?php
$var2 = $_POST['selectCarID'];
$conn = mysqli_connect("192.168.44.122", "dbtjd1", "root", "db");
$query = "SELECT Day FROM hashDB WHERE CarID = '".$var2."'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

?>
        <select name='dayval'>
            <option value=''>-- CHOOSE --</option>
<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    foreach ($row as $field) {

        ?>
            <option value="<?php echo "".htmlspecialchars($field).""; ?>">
                <?php echo "".htmlspecialchars($field).""; ?>
            </option>
        </select>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

I don't have idea on this ..

I really appreciate of you ! 
thanks.

Comment: Do you want to populate your dropdown using php ? Please clearly explain what you want to achieve using this code.

Comment: yes u r right !! sorry for that . i want to show all DBlist in dropbox, not just (--CHOOSE-- and dblist1). @prashantbana

Comment: Make sure $var2 is receiving some values in the first place else the entire code will not work.

Comment: Why are you using concatenation here : `echo "".htmlspecialchars($field)."";` you can simply use `echo htmlspecialchars($field);`

Comment: oh Thanx for adding @prashantbana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you're coding this on the front end use the following code to populate the drop down like so :

```
<select name='dayval'>
  <option value=''>-- CHOOSE --</option>
   <?php

    $var2 = $_POST['selectCarID'];
    $conn = mysqli_connect("192.168.44.122","dbtjd1","root","db");
    $query = "SELECT Day FROM hashDB WHERE CarID = '".$var2."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $field = $row['Day'];
        echo "<option value=".htmlspecialchars($field).">".htmlspecialchars($field)."</option>"; 
      } 
    ?>
</select>
```

In case of an error, do post the error information and other necessary details such as: if you want to run the code on the backend instead of frontend.

Comment: OH. GOD ! Thanx. its so helpful to me ! really thanx !